# Battery selection

Tags: batteries

I'm making a little robot and I can't find a proper battery for it. I thought about CR2032 but it has a very little max current output. I need a battery that can deliver at least 1600mA and a voltage of at least 6V, being as small as posible. Which can I use?

**Edit**
The voltage is trivial, I could use more than one battery.

Comment: Shopping question...

Comment: how many battery types can you name - sounds like a quiz question...

Comment: If you want the size of CR2032 and want it to deliver 1600mA*6V=9.6W that's pretty hard. How long do you want the power to sustain? At that size anything longer than 10 seconds would be expensive, longer than a minute would be impossible.

Comment: (1) Edit your question to make it less of a shopping question or it will probably be closed. (See site rules.) (2) You have forgotten to add capacity specification in mAh. i.e. How long does it have to last. (3) Then you go to one of the reputable suppliers and start looking at their search / comparison for batteries that meet your specification. (4) You then narrow this down by chemistry and recharging options. Fix your question first.

Comment: If you are making a little robot, you should be familiar with other little toys/robots as radio-controlled helicopters/quadcopters etc. But you deserve some credit for dismissing CR2032 batteries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not clear in the question, the fact you're looking at 'button' cells indicates you're having some space and/or weight restrictions. These are the same restrictions RC (remote control) hobbyists are having with their RC models, drones included.

LiPo ([Lithium Polymer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_polymer_battery)) batteries seem to be the standard for such uses because they have incredible capacity and current capabilities for their size/weight. This comes with some disadvantages that could be serious in some cases. LiPo cells can burst in flames or even explode if overcharged or short circuited and they can be permanently damaged if you drain them too much. They also need special chargers.

Another alternative is [Lithium Ion batteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery#Safety). The type used in cell phones and laptops. I haven't read up on them so I can't say anything with certainty but I'm under the impression that they are slightly safer than LiPos.

Comment: FYI, Lithium Polymer is still Lithium Ion.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. Is there a difference?

Comment: The construction differs. The electrolyte formulations are pretty much the same.

Comment: That's interesting. I'm going to look it up.

Comment: @Schizomorph, Battery University is your friend, http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/types_of_lithium_ion

Comment: @Ali Chen, wow. I've never come across such a good resource about batteries. I just had a quick browse and it seems it has everything about them there. I'm certainly saving this for future reference!

Comment: R/C helicopters certainly come down in flames impressively when the batteries fail ....

Comment: @SolarMike, R/C flying things go in flames because the R/C guys use their batteries too aggressively, charge at 10C, discharge at 40C, no protected cells, etc, everything beyond extreme.

Comment: But they do burn well !! burnt patches on the grass , point about protection <> weight... design decisions always have consequences...